# Is there any tutorial about how to edit an Image on Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

Well,

I'm developing an application where i gonna select some picture from my album and then add some another images on this picture.
After that im gonna have a "Save" button where im gonna save on jpg format the "final" image after the user edit the image.
My problem is to display the image i've selected, make the changes adding another images to that one and then save it...
I've found tutorials for displaying one image on screen, another to save, but none about adding images into one image and saving that in the end.
Someone knows how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bitmaps for the images your add on top of your current image? If yes, then try using this function: So basically, you have to detect the touch event on your screen and get the X and Y co-ordinates of the touch event and then pass the original image, the Image you want to add on top your original image, the X co-ordinate and the Y co-ordinate.

```
public Bitmap drawableOnImage(Bitmap imageBackground, Bitmap itemOnImage,
                                      int xScreenOffset, int yScreenOffset)
{

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(imageBackground);
canvas.drawBitmap(imageBackground, 0, 0, null);

canvas.drawBitmap(itemOnImage, xScreenOffset, yScreenOffset, null); 

return Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBackground);

}
```

Comment: I've solved that part already... Now i'm having problem on saving the image... i mean, i pick a picture from my algum, it shows there on my activity... i add another imagems and then when i go to save it, its saving only the part of the image is in exibition on the screen... not all entire image.. do u know what can be?

Comment: @Igor Could you kindly explain "it's saving only the part of the image is in exibition on the screen ... not all the entire image"?
Do you mean that the background image (the picture from your album) is being saved and not the images you add on top? Or do you mean to say that the images you add on the top are being saved and not the background image (picture from your album)? Or do you mean to say something else? Please explain :)

Answer (score 0):

yes i have faced same problem but now it's solved.For solution you can use capture screen and save bitmap in sdcard.If capture screen not working than you can use screen snapshot it's work fine for me.The code like this:-

//it's root layout of your xml layout file
LinearLayout L1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);

//Code which you can use for snapshot

```
            View v1 = L1.getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```

ok i hope it's helpful for you.Ok gdluck

Comment: for save image in sdcard you can use this: File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/imagename.png");
             if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
             try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
 
             } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
             }